# Django: counts forms submitted

Tags: python, django

What I'd like to do with my model is to have and HTML page where to show my users how many question form they have submitted and how much they are still missing (I've five in my original template here I'm repoprting only two) and also for the admin to see how many users in total submitted the forms so this is my code:

```
**HTML**
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <main>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
    <h2>Submission</h2>
    
Total: {{ quest_done }}/2

{% if user.is_superuser %}
Total Question 1: {{ question1_count }}
Total Question 2: {{ question2_count }}
{% endif %}

    </div>
  </main>

{% endblock %}
```

```
**question.models.py**

class QuestionOne(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserInformation, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_1a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
    question_2a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
    question_3a = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
    quest_1_submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '_question_1'

class QuestionTwo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserInformation, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_1b = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
    question_2b = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
    question_3b = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=point)
    quest_2_submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '_question_2'
```

```
**question.views.py**

quest_done = 0
quest_count = 0

def question_one(request):   
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = QuestionOneForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():           
           questionnairename.quest_1_submitted = True
           question1_count = QuestionOne.objects.all().count()
           form.instance.user = request.user           
           form.save()
           messages.success(request, 'Form submitted')           
           if questionnairename.quest_1_submitted == True:
                quest_done += 1
           return redirect('home')
   else:
       form = QuestionnaireNameForm()
   return render(request, 'quest.html', {'form': form, 'quest_count': quest_count, 'question1_count': question1_count})

def question_two(request):   
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = QuestionTwoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():           
           questionnairename.quest_2_submitted = True
           question2_count = QuestionTwo.objects.all().count()
           form.instance.user = request.user           
           form.save()
           messages.success(request, 'Form submitted')           
           if questionnairename.quest_2_submitted == True:
                quest_done += 1
           return redirect('home')
   else:
       form = QuestionnaireNameForm()
   return render(request, 'quest.html', {'form': form, 'quest_count': quest_count, 'question2_count': question2_count})
```

**ERRORS:**
`local variable 'quest_done' referenced before assignment`
and I've not errors for my “question_count” variables, but when I try to show it in my html It is just a blank space. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you can create a separate model for keeping the count and add user as a foreign key. each time the user submits the question, increment the count value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that checks for each model that whether user has submitted the form or not

```
def return_quest_done_count(user):
  count = 0
  count += 1 if QuestionOne.objects.filter(user=user,quest_1_submitted=True) else 0
  ...
  return count
```

And then you can call the function like

```
def question_one(request):
   quest_done = return_quest_done_count(request.user)
   ....
```